# Are there any canonical examples of the Prime Directive being broken that aren't shown on screen?

Tags: star-trek, canon, prime-directive

AFAIK all canonical examples of the prime directive being broken are only by a small number of captains and commanders, which happen to be the ones we're familiar with.

Given how revered Picard and Kirk are, and how they seemingly escape significant punishment for their transgressions, it seems reasonable to assume more captains would be willing to violate it.

> *A rule not enforced is not a rule, but a suggestion*
>
> <sub>~ Me, just now</sub>

Comment: I'd imagine that Picard and Kirk get away with it because they're Picard and Kirk. Lesser captains get their arses handed to them at court martials when they do it.

Comment: @Valorum absolutely, but I would've thought there'd be at least one example of a captain being punished (e.g. stripped of rank) for breaking it.

Comment: Not quite sure why this attracted a downvote, but maybe some wordsmithing might make it more attractive?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I didn't downvote, but maybe because we often close "are there any" questions as they are usually list questions.

Comment: I've always assumed that the reason the examples all seem to be Enterprise-centric is because the Enterprise, as a vessel of research and exploration, is extremely rare.  Most of Starfleet is focused inwards and on what's known; very, very few are just handed the mission of exploring new space and having to spontaneously deal with a crazy variety of unknown threats and civilizations. Though I can't recall what canonical information there is as regards the relative proportion of such exploration vessels.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: I didn't downvote, but after reading the answers and comments, it seems the title and the question body ask two different things. Is it Prime Directive violations (committed by anyone) not shown on screen, or is it Prime Directive violations committed by any of the shows' prolific captains?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Curious, I'm quite the contrary ... I've always disliked the idea of the Enterprise being in any way "special"; I've always imagined the ship and her crew as one of hundreds of exploratory Starfleet vessels, all of which are confronted with unexpected situations and exciting and unique adventures on a regular basis.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Could be, though in an organization the size of Starfleet I would think "hundreds" is still a tiny fraction of their manpower and fleet capacity both. Though it's still enough to make one wonder where the stories of the others doing Enterprise-like things to the prime directive are.  Weirdly, the answers seem to find more potential examples in TOS than anywhere else, even though I feel like the TOS intro and background makes a stronger case that their mission is essentially novel and unique.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well in the technical sense there are several incidents that happen offscreen which become onscreen when the Enterprise has to clean up the mess.  For example...

- In TOS "The Omega Glory" - Captain Ronald Tracey of the USS Exeter
  was helping the Kohms offscreen by supplying phasers in what he hoped
  would be safe passage on an  immortality planet. (See also TNG movie
  *Insurrection*.)  To be fair there was a weird disease that reduced the rest of the crew to mineral crystals so the Captain was stranded.
- In TOS "Bread and Circuses," the Starfleet survey vessel SS *Beagle*
  crashed on space Rome. The Beagle was under the command of Captain R.
  M. Merick.  Though as I write this it's more notable as an example of
  PRESERVING the Prime Directive in a highly dubious way by the captain
  selling his crew into gladiator slavery.
- In TNG "Too Short a Season", decades ago then Captain Jameson resolved a
  hostage crises by selling an alien faction weapons.  But then evened
  it out by selling the other side the same weapons. This was a huge
  Prime Directive fail as it dragged the war out decades longer.  This
  is also extremely similar to a choice Kirk made in TOS "A Private
  Little War" though Kirk's actions were in response to the Klingons
  supplying weapons first.
- TOS "Patterns of Force," Starfleet Academy history professor John Gill
  tried to fix a planet by using Nice National Socialism to get the
  economy going.  It was a really bad idea that happened off-screen.

These examples all died prior to legal consequences.

Comment: If the O/P's question is about intentional violations, I would argue that "Bread and Circuses" would not fit because (1) the crew were stranded and "contamination" (cultural, political, technological) would therefore be unavoidable and inevitable, and (2) it didn't seem to have any real effect anyway - those who survived whatever befell the Beagle mostly didn't survive contact with the indigenous culture, and those who did survive were essentially assimilated.

Comment: @AnthonyX - the crew were stranded because Merik ordered them all down. Prior to that, the ship was damaged but repairable and they expected to repair it.

Comment: Another issue with "Bread and Circuses" is that Merik was not a Starfleet captain.  He had dropped out of the academy.  He was in a different service.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've remembered another example from VOY. Captain Ransom from the USS Equinox committed genocide in an attempt to get his crew home. Like your other examples, he died before he faced consequences from starfleet.

Comment: @IanNewson I have to wonder if that episode would be regarded differently if the interdimensional aliens were established to be as intelligent as food animals.

Comment: "These examples all died prior to legal consequences" - I think that (for at least TOS/TNG era) was TV morality. At least in the 60s, the "good guys" always win and the "bad guys" by some turn of events suffer a fate commensurate with their misdeeds. Example: Merrick ordered his crew to their deaths, committed one small act of redemption by helping Kirk & crew to escape, and was assassinated for it.

Comment: @lucasbachmann  The problem with the Three TOS example is that the Enterprise crew arrives while those violations of the Prime Directive are still ongoing, and thus those violations are seen on screen.  Sand some people might argue the same for the TNG example, though others would argue that it was a historical event mentioned and not seen on screen.  My answer has the only example I am certain of.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: Well, "seen on screen" is what the question title asks for, whereas the question text indicates the OP is actually interested in examples of Prime Directive violations not committed by any of the various shows' captains. OP may want to clarify the criteria, but it seems the thought that there could be Prime Directive violations committed by others, yet seen on screen (this answer), or Prime Directive violations committed by any of the shows' captains, but not (directly) seen on screen (your answer) just didn't occur to them.

Answer (score 7):

The Voyager episode "Q2" has an example.  The episode begins with a history report by Icheb:

> ICHEB: Though it was a blatant violation of the Prime Directive, Kirk saved the Pelosians from extinction, just as he had the Baezians and the Chenari many years earlier. Finally, in the year 2270, Kirk completed his historic five year mission and one of the greatest chapters in Starfleet history came to a close. A new chapter began when Kirk regained command of the Enterprise.

http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/716.htm

So Icheb mentions at least one violation of the Prime Directive (Pelosians), and possibly two others (Baezians and Cenari) which have never been shown onscreen and which happened about a century before the episode.

Comment: Yeah well that's just Icheb's opinion man.

Comment: Further the gist of the original question was more interested in non-main cast examples as I read it.  While Kirk is a trivia answer in Voyager he's not as offscreen as say Kiri-kin-tha's babysitting adventures. Though I salute your find.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Icheb abides.

Answer (score 5):

The novel *Prime Directive*, by Judith and Garfield Reeves Stevens, is entirely about the consequences of Kirk breaking the Prime Directive on the planet Talin.

Comment: Yeah, except that Talin was already being manipulated by off planet actors.  Its development had already been compromised.

Comment: And novels aren't considered canon in Star Trek unlike other franchises (like Star Wars, to an extent.)

Comment: Still a great story though. I especially like the part where Starfleet are terrified of disconnecting the damaged nacelle from the Enterprise, because it's disappearing somewhere one molecule at a time and they're worried it'll go starbow-boom if they futz with it.